# Different way to create component

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the redux tutorial, there are two different ways in creating component. What's the difference？

way1:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)

export default TodoList
```

way2:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.todos.map((todo, index) =>
          <Todo {...todo}
                key={index}
                onClick={() => this.props.onTodoClick(index)} />
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) introduced in react 0.14.

The second one is a class based component that can be used to handle state and has access to the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) of [React.Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

In Redux, stateless functions are mostly used for presentational components and classic class based components are used for container components that care about state. 
More on this topic can be found here: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.mqt3zyon5

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions

> In an ideal world, most of your components would be stateless
>   functions because in the future we’ll also be able to make performance
>   optimizations specific to these components by avoiding unnecessary
>   checks and memory allocations. This is the recommended pattern, when
>   possible.